# Why a first cell of UITableView custom cell is always called twice on action events in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a question about custom cell of UITableView on xcode.

I have two classes, CustomCell and ViewController.

My code is simple.

The ViewController make two CustomCell rows from cellForRowAtIndexPath function, and assigns tag (0,1) for switch button in CustomCell each rows.
( first cell's switch button tag : 0, second one : 1 )

But whenever I click the switch button, only first cell is called twice. Second cell works well.

Furthermore, first cell called two tags.

When I click first cell's switch button,

Log : "first switch button is tapped"

Log : "second switch button is tapped"

When I click second cell's switch button,

Log : "second switch button is tapped"

I need your help. Thanks.

```
- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"certCell";

    CertCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CertCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.switchButton.tag = 0;
            break;

        case 1:
            cell.switchButton.tag = 1;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I connected switch button by action on `CustomCell.m`

Comment: Please share the code for your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: Hmm, you may want to post your CertCustomCell implementation as well.

Comment: CertCustomCell has simple code. SwitchButton action, it has an object casted sender by UIswitch. And switch(object.tag) { case 0 : log "first switch button is tapped", case 1: log "secondswitch button is tapped"}

Comment: Well your cellForRowAtIndexPath looks fine. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Did you put a `break` statement after `case 0`

Comment: Whoops, I just had checked it, and I found that I missed [break]. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"When I click first cell's switch button,

Log : "first switch button is tapped"

Log : "second switch button is tapped" <-- you should add a breakpoint here to find out what code executed before

Sometimes it's hard to find out where the bug is, just add more breakpoints.